# How to configure the aws event bridge to send events to URL as internally or private(VPC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I have deployed my application A and B on AWS ECS and used an application load balancer to make HTTPS protocol. I have created an AWS event bridge event. Here my scenario application A sends an event with data to rule and I configured the target as URL by using  API destination(HTTPS URL of Application B) on event rule. But here I need to avoid Application B become public access. How I need to send the event to Application B as internally either using target as API destination or  AWS API gateway.

Is there possible to send the events to the application deployed on the same AWS as internal communication by using VPC?

Comment: were you able to find the answer for this? as of feb 2022, seems to be there is no way!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [official blog](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/compute/integrating-amazon-eventbridge-and-amazon-ecs/), you can try using [VPC link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-private-integration.html).

"the Application Load Balancer can be hidden from public access and connected to API Gateway through VPC Link."